# Using Chart.js with angular and systemjs: "Chart is not defined"

Tags: angular, chart.js, systemjs, primeng

I'm using the Chart Component in PrimeNG, which depends on Chart.js, so I successfully installed that using npm (version 2.5.0), however, I am now getting the following error when loading the page that uses the chart:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Chart is not
>   defined

I believe this is because I have not properly imported it or included it in my systemjs file, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that. I've tried including it in systemjs the following ways:

```
'chart.js':   'npm:chart.js/dist/Chart.js',
```

and

```
'chart':     'npm:chart.js/dist/Chart.js',
```

And I've tried importing with the following:

```
import { Chart }    from 'chart';
```

and

```
import { Chart }   from 'chart.js';
```

But neither have worked. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Any luck Brett?

Comment: Looking into your solution shortly, sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Brett any update on this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure that this is what's causing your error, but I've encountered this when trying to import an un-typed library into my Angular/TypeScript projects. Specifically Hammer.js - I solved it by grabbing a typed version of the library from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types)

I see a Chart.js and Chartjs in there, try those.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/<libname>
```

edit: I should have continued with this answer. Once you've installed this new library, you would import it from `'@types/<libname>'`, and update your references to the library in the systemjs with the same pattern.